# Build Goals Depedencies

Tags: maven

Does anyone know the Maven build goals dependencies and order?

For instance, if I tell Maven to `clean`, it just cleans. But if I tell Maven to `install`, it also calls `generate-sources`, `compile`, `test`, etc. I am trying to figure out which goals are dependent on which other goals.

I have [found this document](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), but it doesn't show dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sequential in the order mentioned under lifecycle section. You have clean and default lifecycle. The last  command deploy under default lifecycle depends on every other command listed above it in the hierarchy. Similarly every command in a lifecycle depends on other commands listed above it.